# Powershell - Find hive with Specific Name and then add key

Tags: powershell, hive, registry

I'm currently trying to code a something in powershell that will look for a registry hive with the name "c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e" and then add a Binary key in for each instance that has a hive with that name.

I currently have the below code that will add in the code for one example I have manually found.

```
$path = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Profiles\Name Of Outlook Profile\c02ebc5353d9cd11975200aa004ae40e"

New-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 00030354 -PropertyType Binary -Value ([byte[]](0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00)) -Force
```

and I have this bit of code that will search through the HKCU:

```
$listhkcu = get-childItem "HKCU:\" -recurse
```

Any ideas on how I would add this binary key in for each instance of a hive with this name?

Any ideas or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is a bit pedantic but just to make you aware, What you are searching for is a ***key***. you are searching in the HKCU ***hive***. You want to add a ***value***.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Always good to know when using incorrect termonoligy!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
[byte[]]$stuff = $(0x30, 0x02, 0x08, 0xAF)
$path = 'HKCU:\Environment'
New-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 'thing' -Value $stuff -PropertyType Binary
```

[image]

You want to see the value you just created?

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name 'thing'
```

[image]

Now in RegEdit...

[image]

Check your search after the create.

Comment: Ok, this is nice! Although how would I go about finding any key names that has the name "Environment" in then adding that value after each key with the name "Environment" is found? Thanks! :)

Comment: Use something like ```ls 'HKCU:\' -Recurse | where { $_.Name -like '*Environment*' } | Select PSParentPath | ft -AutoSize -Wrap``` to find all the keys with-in the HKCU hive. Iterate over those keys with ```foreach-object``` and add what you want. Back up your registry first :-)

Comment: That works well, I've changed it ever so slightly to get the PSPath rather than the parent. Only issue left is that this has the Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook instead of just starting at HKEY_Current.. etc I tried to do $path.replace ("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER", "HKU:") but I get the error "Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData] does not contain amethod named 'replace'.". But If I do this on a normal variable the .replace part works fine?